# 500 internal server error on live server

Tags: yii

I am having a problem on live server. I am simply rendering a create form. On my local machine it works fine but on live server it throws an error of 500 internal server error. I also checked the log file and there was no error reported.

Using Yii < 2

Answer (score 0):

I debugged the code and found that i used the latest syntax for an array. Which was not supported on live server. So, I reverted the code to the old syntax and now working fine.